# How can I ignore changes to .gitmodules file?

Tags: git, git-submodules, gitignore

I wish to ignore changes made to my `.gitmodules` file. I thought it would be as easy as adding it to `.gitignore`, but Git still tracks changes to this file.

How can I ignore changes to .gitmodules?

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Changes to `.gitmodules` seem like something you would always want to track. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You cannot ignore changes in committed files. If you want to ignore changes in a committed file either you don't change it or restore it afterwards: `git restore .gitmodules` or `git checkout HEAD .gitmodules`

Comment: @Biffen That is entirely correct, it's because the file is already being tracked. Thank you. Also, I guess it's an "XY problem", but my real problem is too complicated for a stack overflow thread.